# Is there a way to get a JSON data from a webpage and pass data into a textbox in c# winform?

Tags: c#, html, json, winforms

I am trying to get a json data from a webpage

`http://localhost/widgets/Screenshot_show/?pc_widget_output_method=JSON`

into my windows form application in c# to a textbox. that is the link to the json data, I am trying to get time properties into a textbox but am not getting it

this is what have tried

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();   //gets an object to access a website
        string download = client.DownloadString("http://localhost/widgets/Screenshot_show?pc_widget_output_method=JSON"); //download the json file into a string
        dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(download); //this function of newtonsoft here deserialize json data 

        string location = (string)dobj["JSON"]["sucess"];

        txtwebclient.Text = download;
```

but am always getting error trying to retrieve that time properties into a textbox

**JSON example**:

```
[
  {
    "name": "",
    "location": "/screenshots/",
    "time": 1584498343,
    "screenshots_id": "1584498343-0-33",
    "creation_time": 1584498343,
    "modified_time": "",
    "__user_id": 1583761141.0404,
    "__update_user_id": null,
    "__user_agent_id": "",
    "__ip": {
      "REMOTE_ADDR": "::1",
      "HTTP_CLIENT_IP": "",
      "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting. usually u cant access ui thread from another method. can you specify the error

Comment: If this is the JSON content, I doubt dobj["JSON"] would return anything. There is also no visible `success` property in the JSON. Can it be: `string location = (string)dobj["location"]`

Answer (score 0):

The json having an array of objects. try this

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(download);
var result = jArray[0]["location"];
```